# set_include_path does not have an effect when used in browser

Tags: php, set-include-path

I am using `set_include_path()` to add to the PHP search path so the server can find the gs executable. Things work as expected when I run the script from the command line (i.e., "`php testpath.php`") but, when I invoke the script from the browser on local-host (Mac OSX 10.11.5), it cannot find the executable. The `testpath.php` file is:

```
$path = '/usr/local/octave/3.8.0/bin';
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . $path);
system("which gs");
```

Is there anything I need to do to get this script working so that it can find the gs executable from a browser invocation? Thanks!

Comment: `set_include_path` sets the PHP path for including PHP files. It doesn't set your shell environment path.

Comment: Ah, of course...Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else had the same problem, I did the following to help convert find the gs executable:

```
system("PATH=/usr/local/octave/3.8.0/bin:\$PATH; /usr/local/bin/magick/convert $src $dst");
```